# select * from @variable? - hacer select a una variable

Tags: sql-server

Realicé un pivote (dinámico) y el resultado lo almaceno en una variable, para mostrar el resultado realizo la siguiente instrucción:

```
exec (@queryimiu)
```

El resultado del pivote lo quiero almacenar en una tabla llamada NuevaTabla:

```
SELECT * INTO NuevaTabla FROM ( 
SELECT * FROM "pivote"
) AS tablefinal
```

Solo que no se como imprimir el pivote (que se encuentra almacenado en la variable **@queryimiu**) en la tabla en "**pivote**"

Comment: intentaste hacerlo con el comando `@execute`, pasando toda tu _consulta_ a una `Query`?

Comment: Si tu `exec @queryimiu` devuelve un único recordset, es posible (no seguro) que puedas hacer un `insert into NuevaTabla (campo1, campo2) exec @queryimiu`, lo has intentado?

Comment: Entiendo que ejecutas instrucciones sql creadas dinámicamente para transponer filas a columnas y en cuyo caso asumo que la cantidad de columnas se desconoce "a priori", ¿verdad?, lo pregunto porque entonces la tabla se tendría que crear respecto a las columnas que resuelve la consulta de selección (SELECT...INTO) y no previo a la inserción.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO testTable (Id, Id2)
SELECT ID, ID2 
from @t
```

En ese ejemplo muy general se puede observar que se inserta a la tabla los valores obtenidos de la variables @t